# why filter doesn't change value in iteration in django template

Tags: python, django

I have custome filter in to_and.py file for getting verbose name

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def verbose_name(objects):
    return objects._meta.verbose_name
```

but when I get the value in view it only give me the first model name in iteration my code queryset has two indivial model

```
 {% load to_and %}
                 {{links}}
              {% for link in links %}
                     {% if link|verbose_name == "Unit" %}
                            {{link|verbose_name}}
                            {{link.id}}
                     {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
```

see the out put of this code
[image]

Comment: print & share links dataset values

Comment: Can you share your models and the view that populates `links` in the context

Comment: In output picture I printed the dataset one is from Unit model and 2nd is SubUnit model but when I iterate its only print Unit model verbose name

Answer (score 0):

in models I forget to change the verbose name of SubUnits

```
just Change the verbose_name in models
class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Unit."""

        verbose_name = 'SubUnit'
        verbose_name_plural = 'SubUnits'
```